iOS Code Signing Error with manual signing
I am facing issues with iOS signing when building my app using Codemagic, but the build works perfectly on my local Mac using automatic code signing.

Codemagic Configuration: Codemagic is connected to my developer portal, and I have created an iOS certificate directly through Codemagic. I also selected the correct provisioning profile available.
Error Message: When trying to build the app in Codemagic, I encounter the following error:


Code Signing Error: "error: exportArchive "Runner.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Associated Domains, Push Notifications, and Sign in with Apple features."


I’ve double-checked in the Apple Developer portal (developer.apple.com) under "Identifiers and Capabilities," and I can confirm that all the necessary capabilities — Associated Domains, Push Notifications, and Sign in with Apple — are activated for the app’s bundle identifier.

Steps I’ve Taken:

Codemagic is linked to my Developer Portal, and the provisioning profile is selected.
I’ve ensured that the required capabilities (Associated Domains, Push Notifications, and Sign in with Apple) are correctly enabled in the Developer portal.

name: Initialize keychain
  script: |
    keychain initialize
name: Add certificates to keychain
  script: |
    keychain add-certificates
name: Set up code signing settings on Xcode project
  script: |
    xcode-project use-profiles
name: Install pods
  script: |
    find . -name "Podfile" -execdir pod install ;
name: Flutter build ipa and automatic versioning
  script: |
    flutter build ipa --flavor production --release \
--build-name=1.0.0 \
--build-number=$(($(app-store-connect get-latest-testflight-build-number "$APP_ID") + 1))
--export-options-plist=/Users/builder/export_options.plist

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

can you provide log output for xcode-project use-profiles step? probably there is something that indicates that wrong or none profiles were used

I fixed it adding a \ after the --build-number argument... that was missing
